# Kotlin can't find TextView (layout)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

i have the problem that Kotlin can't find my TextView or Layout and then crashes with the error

`"Invalid ID 0x00000000 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0"`

and i don't really know why. Here is the code where it's coming from

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.TextView

class TicketsArrayAdapter(context: Context?, tickets: List<Ticket?>?) :
    ArrayAdapter<Ticket?>(context!!, 0, tickets!!) {
    @Suppress("NAME_SHADOWING")
    class TicketsArrayAdapter(context: Context?, tickets: List<Ticket?>?) :
        ArrayAdapter<Ticket?>(context!!, 0, tickets!!) {
        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
            var convertView = convertView
            val ticket = getItem(position)
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView =
                    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.popup_window, parent, false)
            }
            val titleView = convertView!!.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.title_view)
            titleView.text = ticket!!.title
            return convertView
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my Layout with the name popup_window

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Does someone from you might know why this is crashing ? If you need more code just say it.
The whole Log-cat is here

```
E/com.example.dav: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.dav, PID: 21649
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:242)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2581)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1338)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:542)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:425)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:416)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2617)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2224)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:826)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:888)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1960)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2393)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24958)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6784)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24958)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6784)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24958)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6784)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:536)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24958)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6784)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24958)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6784)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24958)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6784)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:1418)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24958)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6784)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:4787)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:4115)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2991)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:10665)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1301)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1309)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:923)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:852)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1283)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8741)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

I tried to fill out the "gaps" aka the R.layout and R.id new and also checked if everything is written right.
I also remade the popup_windows.xml file

Comment: In `getView()` what is the value of parent just before the app crashes?

Comment: How do i do that ? I've tried to add 
'try {
    // code that may cause a crash
} catch (e: Exception) {
    // print the value of the parent object to the console
    println(parent)
    throw e
}'
But it its not giving any Output

Comment: Use the [debugger](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) to set a breakpoint and examine the variable.

Comment: I don't get any Output from that. Its just saying nothing and also not Breaking there.

Comment: OK. Something has an id of zero which is not a valid id. All I can recommend is that you trace the code through, using the debugger, to try to identify where in you code the problem arises. You will than have the problem isolated for further investigation. I would pay especial attention to the section of code inflating layouts.

Comment: Typo. You've inadvertently declared the `TicketsArrayAdapter` class twice, with one nested inside the other. (That's probably where the `@Suppress("NAME_SHADOWING")` annotation came from; the IDE was trying to warn you.) The outer class doesn't have its `getView()` overridden, so it's using `ArrayAdapter`'s, which is trying to load the layout ID passed in the constructor, which is `0`. Remove the three lines starting with that annotation, then even up the closing braces.

Comment: For correctness' sake, I was wrong about where the `@Suppress` annotation came from. I'd incorrectly presumed that "name shadowing" is some generalization of "variable shadowing", but it's apparently just another term for the same thing, and that annotation is only due to the `var convertView = convertView` in `getView()`. There is no warning for duplicate class names, it seems. Just FYI.

Comment: Ok it was my stupidity. I used the class TicketsArrayAdapter twice. Someone also said that, thats how I also saw that problem. Thank you very much guys.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i used the class TicketsArrayAdapter twice and because of that the App crashed. Thanks to everyone that tried to help.